# What's the problem with a PDF not being monotonic?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I solve these two problems below.  In the first, $f(x)$ is monotonic.  In the second, it isn't.  I think the two solutions are the same procedure.  But I'm told this solution method can only be used if $f(x)$ is monotonic.  Why?

Problem $1$.  Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x & \text{ if $0 < x < 1$}\\ 
                       0 & \text{ otherwise.}
          \end{cases}$$

Let $Y = H(X) = e^{-X}$. Compute the PDF $g$ of $Y.$

Problem $2$.  Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF given by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} & \text{ if $-1 < x < 1$}\\
                                   0 & \text{ otherwise.} 
         \end{cases}$$ 
Let $Y = H(X) = X^2$.  Compute $g(y)$, the PDF $g$ of $Y$.

The first problem I can solve by $(1)$ computing the accumulated probability function $G(y)$ of the variable $Y$.  Then $(2)$ I differentiate $G$ with respect to $y$, getting $g(y)$.  Then $(3)$ I determine the domain of $g$, getting the entire definition of the PDF $g$ of $Y$.

I'm told **this won't work for the second problem** because $f(x)$ is not monotonic.  Can you elaborate explaining what is the problem?  **Please use my example-solutions below if it helps.**

Solution to problem $1$.

\begin{align*}
  G(y) &= P(Y \leq y)\\
  &= P\left(\frac{1}{e^X} \leq y\right)\\
  &= P\left(e^X \geq \frac{1}{y}\right)\\
  &= P(X \geq \ln \frac{1}{y})\\
  &= P(X \geq \ln 1 - \ln y)\\
  &= P(X \geq -\ln y)    &&\text{--- since $\ln 1 = 0$}\\
  &= \int_{-\ln y}^\inf 2x\ dx  &&\text{--- notice $0 < -\ln y$}\\
  &= \int_{-\ln y}^1 2x\ dx &&\text{--- after 1, $f(x) = 0$}\\
  &= x^2\rvert_{-\ln y}^1\\
  &= 1 - (-\ln y)^2\\
  &= 1 - (-\ln y)(-\ln y)\\
  &= 1 - \ln^2 y,
\end{align*}

as desired. Now differentiate $G(y),$ getting

\begin{align*}
  g(y) &= G'(y)\\
  &= -2 \ln y \frac{1}{y}\\
  &= -\frac{2}{y} \ln y,
\end{align*}

as desired. The domain is $\frac{1}{e} < y < 1.$

Solution to problem $2$.

\begin{align*}
  G(y) &= P(Y \leq y)\\
      &= P(X^2 \leq y)\\
      &= P(|X| \leq \sqrt{y})\\
  &= P(-\sqrt{y} \leq x \leq \sqrt{y}) &&\text{--- $F(x)$ from $-\sqrt{y}$ to $\sqrt{y}$}\\
  &= P(x \leq \sqrt{y}) - P(x \leq -\sqrt{y})\\
  &= F(\sqrt{y}) - F(\sqrt{y}).
\end{align*}

Now differentiate, getting

\begin{align*}
 g(y) = G'(y)\\
&= f(\sqrt{y}) \frac{1}{2} y^{-\frac{1}{2}} - f(-\sqrt{y})\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)y^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt y}\\
&= \frac{2}{4\sqrt y}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} y^{-\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{align*}

Since $x \in (-1, 1)$ we get $y \in (-1,0) \cup (0,1).$

I don't see a difference in the solution-procedure.  I feel I'm doing the same thing in each case.

Comment: It is not the PDF that should be monotonic. It is the function of the random variable that you take. It is a problem of inverting the transformation. Example: if X is uniform on (-1,1), it is not true that you can simply integrate its PDF from 0 to $\sqrt{x}$ to get the CDF of $X^2$. You have to include negative values of x too.

Comment: However, really this means that you must solve $X^2 \leq x$ (an inequality, not an equation anymore) to get the CDF of $X^2$.

Comment: Hm, I understood the wrong thing.  It is the function of the random variable that must be monotonic.  That makes sense now.  But I'm still pondering about the difference in the solutions.  I also see I wrote $x$ at some point in the solution to the second problem when I think I should've written $X$.  Nevertheless, you can add your comment as an answer as I can see the question is answered.  I just need more time to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for monotonicity of the PDF; not having that does not hurt anything. The issue is with monotonicity of the change of variable. The main point is that to compute the PDF of $G(X)$, you should pass through its CDF, meaning that you should compute $P(G(X) \leq x)$. If $G$ is strictly increasing, then this is $P(X \leq G^{-1}(x))$; if $G$ is strictly decreasing, then this is $P(X \geq G^{-1}(X))$*. If $G$ is neither strictly increasing nor decreasing, then this is $P(X \in G^{-1}((-\infty,x])$, and that preimage could take a wide variety of forms. For example, when $G(x)=x^2$, $G^{-1}((-\infty,x])=[-\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x}]$, which comes into play in the second problem.

* If $G$ has jumps, then it will not be surjective, but in this case there is a kind of "generalized inverse" that can be used. Let me know if you want clarification about this.